# Some important files (sysctl.conf, ufw, ssh_config, etc.) are 'FAILED' in debsums

Tags: debian, security

I have some packages installed not from the official Debian repositories, so I was looking for something that somehow checks the integrity of the system. [The `debsums` packackage](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/debsums/debsums.1.en.html) seems to do exactly that, by checking the MD5 sums of installed Debian packages.

I executed `sudo debsums -a | grep -v OK` which gave the following output:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1.0.0                              FAILED
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/desktop.conf                                      FAILED
/etc/ssh/ssh_config                                                       FAILED
/etc/sysctl.conf                                                          FAILED
/etc/systemd/journald.conf                                                FAILED
/etc/default/ufw                                                          FAILED
```

I noticed that these are ***some*** of the configs that I have manually touched before. There are lot more configs that I've changed but they are not shown, apparently. Does this mean that the packages of the `FAILED` configs above are actually altered (potentially maliciously), or an expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The ones that you manually edited can be ignored. My recommendations for the other ones is to copy them, e.g to a .bk file, then delete them (provided they are not essential at that moment), reinstall their owning package, then compare the difference between the new one and the copied one. Remember that some utilities modify configs automatically.

Answer (score 0):

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1.0.0 is a gpu library.
It may have been modified if you installed a gpu driver outside of the apt system.

The rest are config files that you likely edited.